# Slice vs normal assignments

Tags: python, list, slice

I stumbled upon `UserList`'s implementation and don't seem to understand why in the `__init__()` method both slice assignments and normal assignments are used to set the given initial list. Here's the [code](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/UserList.py):

```
class UserList(collections.MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, initlist=None):
        self.data = []
        if initlist is not None:
            # XXX should this accept an arbitrary sequence?
            if type(initlist) == type(self.data):
                self.data[:] = initlist
            elif isinstance(initlist, UserList):
                self.data[:] = initlist.data[:]
            else:
                self.data = list(initlist)
```

Why are both `self.data[:]` and `self.data` used when assigning the initial list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the code *is* redundant. But it wasn't in 2000 when [Jeremy Hylton made the change](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/c160749acff8).

*Now* slice assigment takes any sequence type, but that feature was only added in [Python 2.3](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices) (specifically, it was Alex Martelli who [added support for any type to be used](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/e9aa394c7191)).

So at the time the code was written, it made perfect sense to make use of slice assignment and not create a new list object, but only if you had an object that actually could be used on the right-hand side for such an assignment. Slice assignment was a fast and efficient way to copy the list contents over.

Comment: I understand. But why use slice assignment anyway if it could have been done without it, similar to the third assignment?

Comment: @AndreiHorak: why create a new list object *again*? Slice assignment saves you from creating a new object here. You could just use `self.data = list(initlist) if initlist is None else []` *now*, of course; e.g. copy `initlist` if it exists otherwise create an empty list. But a slice assignment can be *very* efficient when the other type is a list too.